# Securing Javascript API key

Tags: javascript, security, dropbox-api

I'm using the Dropbox API in a current project & I intend to push & host on github. Do I need to secure the access token for the API & if so, how do I go about this?

```
var Dropbox = require('dropbox');
var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: '####' });
```

Dropbox requires you set a URL for use with the app you're creating but I'm not sure if that's enough?

Thanks in advance,

Rory

Comment: Related: https://gist.github.com/derzorngottes/3b57edc1f996dddcab25

Comment: @yuriy636 This is great, thanks - but how would you hide the key when the code is deployed?

Comment: That is another matter and the thing is the key is never secure in client side, you would need to make requests from your backend, where the key can be kept secret.

Answer (score 0):

Never push any api keys to github.